# Wanting to filter certain objects within an array before it returns the result, how would I properly use the .filter() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating an order function app and the website I'm doing it for doesn't define all the tags in originally tags. For example, what I'm wanting to scrap is the size, but the the size as well as other fields within the same block are only defined by the `<p>` tag.

I have a function that collects all the objects within that block and pushes it into an array then pushed into an embed where it sends all the results. I've been trying to come up with a solution to pull on the "size" only within the block, but it returns null or sends the entire block. I read up that JS has a built in function called `.filter()` that potentially could be of use for this type of situation.

How would I go about approximately integrating the `.filter()` function to filter the other `<p>` tags out and only include that one I'm targeting?

Below I have attached my code for the size scraping as well as a screenshot of the HTML.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxHAk.png)

```
await page.waitForSelector(".responsive-body-3-2.mr12-lg.mb2-sm.pt3-sm.flx-gro-sm-1.flex-parent.d-sm-flx.flx-dir-sm-c.flx-jc-sm-sb.flx-ai-sm-fs");

let sizeInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let sizeTag = document.querySelectorAll(".responsive-body-3-2.mr12-lg.mb2-sm.pt3-sm.flx-gro-sm-1.flex-parent.d-sm-flx.flx-dir-sm-c.flx-jc-sm-sb.flx-ai-sm-fs");
    let size = [];
    sizeTag.forEach((tag) => {
        size.push(tag.innerText)
    })
    return size;
});
console.log('Size has been collected!')
```

Comment: What site is this, please? It's hard to help without the ability to run a [mcve]. `[data-testid="Product Size"]` seems like a much more reliable selector than the giant list of classes.

Comment: The site is nike.com

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not very specific. I don't see these sizes on that page. To get help, there should be a complete, runnable snippet with the actual site that I can copy-paste into my editor and play with.

Comment: I can PM you the link of the website as well as the order number and email that you use to see that info so you can play around with it?

Comment: Sorry, the point of the site is to create a resource for future visitors, so answering privately would defeat the purpose. I only do that sort of 1-on-1 work for compensation.